# error: invalid operands to binary expression std::map[Callback]

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

My code:

```
// MyTemplate.h
template <class T>
class MyTemplate {
    typedef void (T::*CbMethod)();
    typedef std::map< CbMethod, std::string> FMap;

    
    FMap myMap;
    void function(CbMethod para) {
       CbMethod m = para;
       myMap[m] = "my name"; // error here 
    }
```

It's giving this error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void
> (MyListener::*const)()' and 'void (MyListener::*const)()')

EDIT

Code used

```
class Listener {
   void start() {
     MyTemplate *var = new MyTemplate < Listener >(this);
     var->function(&Listener::ready);
   }
   
   void ready() {
    // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume that the error isn't in the specified place. The template should compile on itself.

Comment: Post a full, minimal compilable example with a `main()` and all required `#includes`, and a full error message that includes line/column diagnostics.

Comment: Pointers to members can't be compared by `operator<`, which is required by `std::map` when used as key.

Comment: did you perhaps confuse key with mapped value? I could understand a `std::map<std::string,CbMethod>`, but I don't understand what a `std::map<CbMethod,std::string>` would be good for

Comment: Off-topic: There's no need to copy parameters into local variables, parameters are already themselves. So instead of `CbMethod m = para; myMap[m] = ...` you could simply have `myMap[para] = ...`

Comment: Hmm thanks for the answers. tried to assign function name to the map to use in loggers.
myMap[m] = BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(m)